# Question of limit 1/log(x without lhopital

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

$\lim_{x\to\infty}{{\log \log \left(1+{{1}\over{x}}\right)}\over{\log x}}$

I cant do it. If somebody can do the question for me. I need do to the test but I not allowed use l'hopital.

Comment: (1/log(x))*log(log(1+(1/x)))

Comment: Use the fact that for any $\alpha\in (0,1)$ there exists $M_{\alpha}>0$ such that, for all $x>M_{\alpha}$, $$\frac\alpha x\le \log\left(1+\frac1x\right)\le \frac1x$$

Comment: What is the definition of $\alpha$?

Comment: @Multivariablecalculus A real number in the said interval?

Comment: is not α sorry. It is a infinite symbol

Comment: it isn t α. it is  ∞

Comment: I am referring to the statement of the problem. From what has been stated, $\alpha$ could be an arbitrary real value, i.e. $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}.$ @G.Sassatelli

Comment: @multivariablecalculus $\alpha$ is a number arbitrarily close to $1$. Think of $1-\varepsilon$.

Comment: @Multivariablecalculus It was a questionable choice of latex ( {\it \propto} instead of \infty ).

Comment: oh yes now i understand

Comment: If we put $1/x = t$ we can see that $$\dfrac{\log\log(1 + (1/x))}{\log x} = -\frac{\log\log(1 + t)}{\log t} = -\frac{\log((1/t)\log(1 + t)) + \log t}{\log t} = -1 - \frac{\log((1/t)\log (1 + t))}{\log t} \to -1 + 0$$ as $ t \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$\log(1+1/x)
\approx 1/x
$
for large $x$
(easy to show from
$\log(1+z)
=\int_1^{1+z} \frac{dy}{y}
$,
from which you get
$\frac{z}{1+z} < \log(1+z) < z$),
${{\log \log \left(1+{{1}\over{x}}\right)}\over{\log x}}
\approx {{\log (1/x)}\over{\log x}}
= {-\log (x)\over{\log x}}
\to -1
$.

Comment: you use lhopital? i dont understand Integral because i havent this matery yet

Comment: The integral is how log is *defined*. L'hopital is not used at all.

Answer (score 1):

By multiplying x,

$\displaystyle\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log\log(1+\frac{1}{x})}{\log x} = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log \frac{x\log (1+1/x)}{x}}{\log x} = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log\log(1+1/x)^x-\log x}{\log x} = (\log\log e) (0) - 1$

$=-1$

Answer (score 1):

---

> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I used on the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality to show that the logarithm function satisfies the inequalities
>
> $$\frac{x-1}{x}\le \log(x)\le x-1 \tag 1$$
>
> for $x>0$.

---

Using $(1)$, it is straightforward to show that

$$\frac{-x}{x-1}\le \frac{\log\left(\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)\right)}{\log(x)}\le \frac{1/x-1}{\frac{x-1}{x}}=-1$$

whereupon application of the squeeze theorem yields the coveted limit

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\log\left(\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)\right)}{\log(x)}=-1$$

> Note that we did not rely on L'Hospital's Rule, expansions, or other tools from differential calculus.  Rather, we only used the inequality in $(1)$, which was obtained from elementary analysis, and the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Use *equivalents*:

$\log(1+u)\sim_0 u$, hence $\log\Bigl(1+\dfrac 1x\Bigr)\sim_\infty\dfrac1x$. As it doesn't approach $1$, there results that
$$\log\log\Bigl(1+\dfrac 1x\Bigr)\sim_\infty -\log x,\enspace\text{whence}\quad \frac{\log\log\Bigl(1+\dfrac 1x\Bigr)}{\log x}\sim_\infty\frac{-\log x}{\log x}=-1.$$